# How to send call audio via WebSocket with any tools

Tags: audio, websocket, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, chunks

i have to perform a load testing by sending audio files chunks via websocket ,i tried all the websocket sampler in jmeter but seems no luck .I am able to make connection by using WebSocket Single Write Sampler but not able to send audo files .

help needed on same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the websocket request payload either using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) if you're trying to simulate the browser network footprint or via a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Once you capture the request(s) associated with transferring of the audio file you should be able to paste it to the WebSocket Single Write Sampler

[image]

References:

- [Sample test plans](https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers/tree/master/samples) covering various aspects of simulating WebSocket traffic with JMeter
- [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)

Comment: i am already doing this ,all i asking how to send audio chunks